# Using $location service with non SPA

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a non SPA angularjs app. Routing from my server works fine but the problem I have encountered is that the $location service seems unable to understand my url. For example, if I have http://localhost:9000/test/item?id=abc123 and I call $location.search() in my controller, it returns an empty object. It appears as though angular always assumes there is a hash (#) in your url. I tried using the $locationProvider to turn on html5 mode and in this mode $location.search() will return an object with id=abc123 as expected. However, with html5 mode turned on, non of my links are hitting up the server for routing anymore. The url in the address bar gets changed but no server call is made.

So, how do you build a non SPA site with angular and still make use of the $location service for parsing query params. Is this possible or do I have to write my own url parser?

update: I am using angular 1.3.15